Exit time squared of 3D Brownian motion
I am running simulations of 3D Brownian motion (starting at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$), recording the exit time from the unit-sphere, and plotting them all in a normalized histogram in order to fit a curve that would approximate the density of the exit time. According to the following post,  Expected value of exit time of Brownian motion

in my case, if we denote $\tau$ as the exit time, $\mathrm{E}[\tau]=1/3$. How can I find $\mathrm{E}[\tau^2]$? My goal is to use this to get $\mathrm{Var}[\tau]$ and fit a beta-distribution to the histogram with mean $\mathrm{E}[\tau]$ and variance $\mathrm{Var}[\tau]$. Any help is greatly appreciated.
